# How to switch from HttpWebRequest to HttpClient?

Tags: c#, curl, post, httpclient, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send a request through `HttpClient` and read a response. This is the curl from which I tried to do this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data \
'{comment: {text: "vulgar content"},
  languages: ["en"],
       requestedAttributes: {TOXICITY:{}} }' \
https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

I've tried something likes this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent("{comment: {text: \"vulgar\"},\n       languages: [\"en\"],\n      requestedAttributes: {TOXICITY:{}} }");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

And this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");

    HttpContent postData = new StringContent("{comment: {text: \"what kind of idiot name is foo?\"},\n       languages: [\"en\"],\n       requestedAttributes: {TOXICITY:{}} }");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze?key=AIzaSyCZdLeFtJhbqD9_WJ2Q4UiDB-THRzQhp5g", postData);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var x = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something when request fails
            return true;
    }
 }
```

However both of those snippets just break on the `response` part. No exception, no communicates, console says programe ends with code 0. But sending it via `HttpWebRequest` works just fine:

```
var url = "https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE";
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
var data = @"{comment: { text: ""what kind of idiot name is foo?""},languages: [""en""], requestedAttributes: {TOXICITY:{}} }";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(data);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong in sending it through `HttpClient`? I'm replacing `YOUR_KEY_HERE` with my API key.

Comment: What do you mean by "just break" exactly? What have you done to add extra diagnostics? Can you provide a [mcve] that shows the problem? (The issue could well be in the calling code, for example, and how you're using asynchrony.) Without a [mcve] it's going to be much harder to help you.

Comment: An entire snippet is a whole function I tried. I tried both calling it synchronously and asynchronously. I just pack whole snippet into a method and call it on console. I also tried both making a method static. I tried debugging it and program ends before it hits the 'response' part.

Comment: are you sure the content part is in right formate?

Comment: Your HWR version is synchronous, your HC version is asynchronous. I suspect you haven't actually done anything to prevent your console app from finishing normally (falling out of the end of its main) when it hits the first point that things go async. Do your tests in a GUI app instead or show us the full program (all of static void Main). If nothing else make sure the very last statement in Main is a Console.ReadLine

Comment: Yes, Caius, you're right. I just found what I did wrong and posted answer. The call wasn't awaited so program finished before the the response got there (average request time takes 2-3 seconds).

Comment: I guess you might have also had warnings of "because this call is not awaited.." - look into those when you get hem, as they're normally an indicator of some unexpected behavior waiting to surprise you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so following [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) advice on providing reproducable example, I noticed that my Task wasn't marked as async. So I solved it by making a request in async Task method:

```
public async Task<string> FirstSnippet()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze?key=AIzaSyCZdLeFtJhbqD9_WJ2Q4UiDB-THRzQhp5g"))
        {
            request.Content = new StringContent("{comment: {text: \"vulgar\"},\n       languages: [\"en\"],\n      requestedAttributes: {TOXICITY:{}} }");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

            using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

And calling method in Main:

```
Program p = new();
Console.WriteLine(await p.FirstSnippet());
```

Comment: Right - that's what I *suspected* was happening, but without the [mcve], we couldn't know. The lesson to learn from this is to come up with a complete example before asking a question - often, just coming up with that will be enough to let you solve the problem yourself.